# Script to copy certain cells from one sheet and paste in another sheet on next empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

my first post here and need your expert help. Here is [link to the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hZwlnIFeRu11DHa-z54jhhu1LLek-7AYAfU1BQsQ-Zk/edit?usp=sharing). I posted on Google Groups and they told me come here.

I have a one sheet that is a customer return form (namely Returnform). I fill this form and print it for sending to customers and for record.

I wanted to know if it is possible to copy certain cells such as customer name(F9), website order #  (F8) and few others to another sheet (namely Customer Returns) that is basically log of all customer returns.

Ideally I want to create a script that copies these certain cells to appropriate columns in Customer Returns sheet on the NEXT row. i.e. doesn't overwrite previous entries. I will then assign this script to a button. If we pull this off, I will be able to keep record of all my previous customer returns

I have looked on many posts through googling and found few almost similar cases but they had some differences and hence not usable for me. I am not even a beginner with scripts, so that's why I am here.

Thanks!

Edit: My bad, added link to dummy file for ease of understanding or trying code. Both of below codes are present in dummy file as projects.

**FIRST PIECE OF CODE**

```html
function CopyPaste() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Returnform');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Customer returns');            
   sheet1.getRange('E8').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B2'))
   sheet1.getRange('E22').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('C2'))
   sheet1.getRange('K6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('D2'))
}
```

**PROBLEMS:**
1. Is not dynamic i.e. pastes over same row of data instead of next empty row.
2. Pulls formulas not values, so causes some problems.

**SECOND PIECE OF CODE**

```html
function addReturnRequest() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Returnform");
    var sa = sh.getDataRange().getValues();  // Get everything
    sh = ss.getSheetByName("Customer Returns");
    var count = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,1).getValue();
    // Build the row on Customer Returns
    count++;
    var da = [];
    da.push(count);
    da.push(sa[8][5]); // Name F9
    da.push(sa[7][5]); // Order F8
    da.push(sa[21][4]); // Qty E22
    da.push("");
    da.push("");
    da.push(sa[21][11]); // L22
    Logger.log(da);
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,da.length).setValues([da]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

**PROBLEMS:** 
1. I don't understand it
2. I doesn't show any error when I run it but neither works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. Have you tried writing any scripts at all? Show what you have tried so far, including that you know how to set up a script and run it and load a menu button, etc. Here is a [place you can start.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions)

If you really don't have any idea how to write a script then I recommend doing this all with formulas rather than scripts, which would get you most of the way there (although short of a click of a button). Just pull in the cells you need in the new row and copy and paste as values each time you fill out a return form.

If you want more specific help link to a dummy spreadsheet and/or show what scripts you've written.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain. . I have narrowed down to two pieces of code. First one is this: 

`function CopyPaste() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Returnform');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Customer returns');            
   sheet1.getRange('E8').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B2'))
   sheet1.getRange('E22').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('C2'))
   sheet1.getRange('K6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('D2'))
}`

This one pulls required cells to other sheet but has 2 issues:
1 It gets formulas not values

Comment: 2nd issues is that it pastes over the cells as specified in code i.e. B2, C2, D2. So, it doesn't paste on the next empty row. 

Sorry, I have added link to the dummy file in post

Comment: Look up getLastRow in the documentation, and use with getRange(row, column, height, width)